# Involution on the set of all multipliers of $A$ ($A$ is a $C^*$-algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. $M(A)$ denotes the set of all multipliers of $A$, i.e. $m\in M(A)$ means that there is a map $m^*:A\to A$ such that $m(a)^*b=a^*m^*(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$.

I want to know why $*:M(A)\to M(A),\; m\mapsto m^*$ defines an involution on $M(A)$. I already know that $(m^*)^*=m$ and $(m\circ n)^*=n^*\circ m^*$ for every $m,n\in M(A)$.

But why is $(\lambda m+\mu n)^*=\overline{\lambda}m^*+\overline{\mu} n^*$ for every $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{C}$,$m,n\in M(A)$? I think it is an easy calculation, but maybe I have seen too many stars today and now I'm confused. But i'm stuck.

My try: $((\lambda m+\mu n)(a))^*b=\overline{\lambda}m(a)^*b+\overline{\mu}n(a)^*b=\overline{\lambda}a^*m^*(b)+
\overline{\mu}a^*n^*(b)$ for every $b\in A$. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (which happens often) your first paragraph makes no sense: that is not what multipliers are, and besides you want to define what  $m^*$ means.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, sorry. What is wrong? This is the definition of multipliers we had in lecture.

Comment: I guess it's fine. It depends on showing that such a thing exists, though. So the usual approach is to just define the multipliers in terms of left and right multipliers.

Comment: This definition in terms of adjointable operators on $A$ is useful when you are dealing with Hilbert-$C^\ast$-modules and it is an easy exercise to show that it coincides with the usual definition via double centralizers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done: 
\begin{align}
((\lambda m+\mu n)(a))^*b&=\overline{\lambda}m(a)^*b+\overline{\mu}n(a)^*b=\overline{\lambda}a^*m^*(b)+
\overline{\mu}a^*n^*(b)=a^*(\bar\lambda m^*(b)+\bar\mu n^*(b))\\
&=a^*(\bar\lambda m^* +\bar\mu n^*)(b).
\end{align}
But now you know that $((\lambda m+\mu n)(a))^*b=a^*(\lambda m+\mu n)^*(b)$. If you look at the right-hand sides, you have shown that 
$$
a^*(\bar\lambda m^* +\bar\mu n^*)(b)=a^*(\lambda m+\mu n)^*(b)
$$
for all $a,b$, which implies $\bar\lambda m^* +\bar\mu n^*=(\lambda m+\mu n)^*$.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have already helped me a lot!